# Check if portion of string in a list exists in another list

Tags: python, string, substring

I have the following lists below:

```
x1 = ['Apples:Red',
      'Apples:Green',
      'Bananas:Yellow',
      'Grapes:Purple',
      'Grapes:Green']
x2 = ['Green', 'Yellow']
```

I would like to check if the substring after the colon in list `x1` matches with the any of the strings in `x2`.

Looking for an output like this:

```
['Apples:Green',
 'Bananas:Yellow',
 'Grapes:Green']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this (`rhs` = right-hand side):

```py
x1 = ['Apples:Red', 'Apples:Green', 'Bananas:Yellow', 'Grapes:Purple', 'Grapes:Green']

x2 = ['Green', 'Yellow']


list_new = []
for substring in x1:
    rhs = substring.split(":")[1]
    if rhs in x2:
        list_new.append(substring)

>>> list_new
['Apples:Green', 'Bananas:Yellow', 'Grapes:Green']
```

Answer (score 0):

If `x2` is in any way significant, turn it into a `set` before doing lookups:

```
s2 = set(x2)
```

A list comprehension should do the rest:

```
[x for x in x1 if x.split(':', 1)[-1] in s2]
```

Passing `maxsplit=1` to `str.split` ensures that only the first `:` results in a split.